# How to write browser tests with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm developing a client JavaScript library using Microsoft's TypeScript. I'd like to write some tests and, ideally, run them in-browser (rather than via node.js).

None of the official [TypeScript Samples](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Samples) contain test code, so there's no guidance there.

I've found at least [one example](https://github.com/varju/typescript-node-mocha-example/blob/master/test/models/user_model.spec.ts) of combining TypeScript and Mocha, but it runs under Node. I'm developing for the browser, so I'd prefer to test in the browser.

My current approach is to compile my library into a single JS file using `grunt-typescript` and `grunt-browserify` to inline the `require` statements. I then load this and the tests files into my test runner:

```html
<script src="../build/library.js"></script>
<!-- external test dependencies -->
<script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>

<!-- the tests -->
<script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
<script src="../build/test/my-test.js"></script>
```

This doesn't work at all, however. My test needs to `import` the code it's testing, and the browser doesn't understand how to process the resulting `require` statement in the compiled code. My attempts to use `requirejs` have all ended in futility.

How can I test TypeScript code? I'd like to be able to:

- Run the tests in the browser (preferably using [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/) and [Chai](http://chaijs.com/)).
- Test code complex enough that it has import another file in the same project.
- Include some dependencies on external node modules.

Comment: I would revise the question to ask about how to get requirejs working and include the specific problem you are having. I'm using requirejs with tsUnit and I have also used it with Jasmine and it works fine - so if you solved that problem I expect your Mocha/Chai combination would work too.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. Is [this project](https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/TypeScriptUtilities) the one you referred to using Jasmine and require.js? I'll try using it as a template.

Comment: That one doesn't use require, although it does use Jasmine. I used them together on a commercial software product - and blogged about the little trick you need: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201407/Blog/Combining-TypeScript-Jasmine-And-AMD-With-RequireJS/

Comment: You should run your tests against Jasmin and PhantomJs, you don't have to load the test files into your html.
And there's no special behaviour for working with TypeScript, except that you have to compile it, all the rest is the same as working with JavaScript...

Comment: The blog post, http://sitepen.com/blog/2015/03/24/testing-typescript-with-intern , explains how you can write TypeScript tests using Intern ( http://theintern.io/ , which also uses Chai).

Comment: @danvk Did you settle on a satisfactory solution? If so, maybe you could post it as an answer here?

Comment: I wound up switching to [Flow](http://flowtype.org/). You can find my code [here](https://github.com/hammerlab/pileup.js). The other bit of my solution was to compile all my tests into a single bundle which I run in-browser using the Mocha test runner. For automated testing, I load this using mocha-phantomjs. You could do the same with typescript tests.